# which is good creating void* to object or making self referential?

Tags: c++

C-Interface is created for C++ API. 
some variable are defined for C++'s API object like :

```
typedef struct object* object;
```

other approach is used

```
typedef void* object;
```

My lead suggested  that  `typedef struct object* object` this is good . But I don't understand why this is better design.
Which is good design and why ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not a good idea to throw away type information. Or for that matter any useful information.

Comment: For black-box structures (like `FILE` in C) go with the first alternative. But I recommend you do like `FILE` and don't define the type-alias as a pointer.

Comment: @Nawaz I think my question is different from question you marked as duplicate. In that question class is declared already. But here i am only making object to struct object*. sorry if i am wrong.

Comment: @vidhugangwar: Here you are discussing two approaches, both of them are discussed in the other thread. Apart from them, the other thread also mentions a third approach.